# deshabilitar un checkbox despues de seleccinarlo

Tags: javascript, html, dom, perl

muestro una lista de checkbox, el usuario podrá seleccionar los que desee, sin embargo el checkbox seleccionado se debe deshabilitar para no volver a seleccionarse, lo estoy realizando con **javascript** utilizando la función **onclick** al seleccionarse el checkbox.

Cada una de los checkboxs los concateno formando una cadena PERO LO MAS IMPORTANTE ES QUE LOS DEBO DESHABILITAR para que no se vuelvan a reelegir y no logro deshabilitarlos.

Por favor, me podrán brindar algún tip, no doy con el error, si tecleo 3 veces el mismo checkbox me lo muestra 3 veces y solo debe ser 1.

Respeto para Ustedes

Comment: Adjunta parte de tu código para que se te pueda ayudar mejor. Por otro lado, ¿una vez que marqué un checkbox no puedo cambiar mi elección?

Comment: Mejora tu pregunta,adjunta parte de lo que llevas

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Sí entiendo la pregunta, sería que cuando des click a un checkbox, inmediatamente se deshabilite.

En caso de que sea así, te pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
check.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.disabled = true
}
```

Aquí lo que hago es que al hacer un click en un checkbox, a la propiedad disabled de este checkbox le asignamos un valor de "true". Espero te ayude.